# Is there a jBPM 7.5.0 release for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

I've been trying to install jBPM in Tomcat 8 and I haven't been able to find the distribution war files for tomcat. In the "Downloads" section of the jBPM website there's only the option to download the 7.5.0 binaries or an installer that runs on Wildfly.

Is there a jBPM 7.5.0 distribution for tomcat? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Files are at:  [JBPM 7.5 Final](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jbpm/jbpm/7.5.0.Final/)

Instructions for Centos:

1. Get the file:

   wget https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jbpm/jbpm/7.5.0.Final/jbpm-7.5.0.Final-project-sources.tar.gz
2. Install maven

   yum install -y apache-maven
3. Verify the integrity of the file with what is listed on the website.

   md5sum jbpm-7.5.0.Final-project-sources.tar.gz
4. Unzip the file.

   unzip jbpm-7.5.0.Final-project-sources.tar.gz
5. Untar the file.

   tar -xf jbpm-7.5.0.Final-project-sources.tar
6. Build the project.

   mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dfull
7. Search for the war file

   find . -name *.war -print
8. Copy the war file to tomcat/webapps/

   Example location: /etc/tomcat/webapps/
9. Change the ownership pf the file.

   chown tomcat:tomcat /etc/tomcat/webapps/*
10. Change SELinux settings.

    chcon -h system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 /etc/tomcat/webapps/ -R
11. I have not gotten it to work yet but here are [instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.3/html/installation_guide/sect_the_generic_deployable_bundle_installation#setting_up_transaction_manager).

Comment: I followed the steps, the step 6 succeded but the result of step 7 is only:
./jbpm-container-test/jbpm-remote-ejb-test/jbpm-remote-ejb-test-app/target/ejb-services-app.war
I don't think this is the jbmp distribution war. (I'm building version 7.6.0.Final) Any idea?